# Python how to retrieve data in array

Tags: python, arrays

First I am not sure if this is an array. But this is pyzbar decoding an image of a QRcode

```
>>> from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> barcode = decode(Image.open('qr111.png'))
>>> print(barcode)
[Decoded(data='812', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=1166, top=306, width=336, height=336), polygon=[Point(x=1166, y=306), Point(x=1166, y=642), Point(x=1502, y=642), Point(x=1502, y=306)])]
```

I want to retrieve specifically the value "812" of data, how do I do it?
I tried print(barcode[Decoded(data)]) to no avail.

Comment: Try `print(barcode[0].data)`. `Decoded` looks like name of type in that case, and outer `[..]` looks like a list.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you what you want:

```
barcode[0].data
```

It's all in the [source code](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/blob/8e3e87da17ddd794842b2fcbbe0dd86c692d7511/pyzbar/pyzbar.py#L26).